# When using AngularFire, the cursor jumps to end of field while typing

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I setup a tiny sample app that edits one field. But when I type in that field the contents keep reverting back to a second ago.  I'm looking for a fix to AngularFire that makes it just work, or a RTFM where I'm just not initializing it right.  At this point bindTo() is not useable and I can't move forward on using AngularFire at all.

Here's the full sample (and you can open it at http://jsbin.com/wabafu/3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.19/firebase.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.8.0/angularfire.min.js'></script>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module("myapp", ["firebase"]);
      function MyController($scope, $firebase) {
        var ref = new Firebase("https://stackoverflow25331760.firebaseIO.com/"),
            syncObject = $firebase(ref).$asObject();
        syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "data");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MyController">
    <h3>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="EditMode"> Enable Editing
    </h3>
    <div ng-if="EditMode">
      <input type="text" ng-model="data.SyncValue" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!EditMode">
      {{data.SyncValue}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works smooth when only open in one browser, but when open in multiple, I can't type more than a word or two without the text contents reverting back to a few keystrokes ago and the cursor moving to the end of the field.

I imagine the events happening are:

1. I type, the value gets updated in angularjs (GOOD)
2. Angularfire sends the new value to firebase (GOOD)
3. Firebase sends the value to other browsers (while I continue typing) (GOOD)
4. Other browsers receive the new value and update their html (GOOD)
5. Other browsers re-send the value back to firebase as if it was new info (REALLY BAD)
6. Firebase receives this echoed outdated value and pushes it back to me (BAD)
7. My browser gets this second-old value and since it's different than what's now in my text field, the contents of my fiedl gets reverted (BAD)

Am I imagining the process wrong?  What should I do to stop step 5?

P.S. While testing, I found I can work around #7 by typing only a few characters quickly and then waiting 2 seconds, repeat.  That way the value doesn't change while the sync is echoing and my cursor won't jump.

P.P.S. To try to narrow it down, I've made a checkbox that controls if the data is displayed in a field, or just a read-only div.  Even if the second browser is only displaying the data, this echo/reverting behavior still exists in the first browser.  The only way for data to store in firebase correctly is if I only have one browser using it at a time.

Comment: Please include the minimal, relevant code in your question.

Comment: I've included the minimal code and tested it still has the problem behavior.

Comment: When doing a shared whiteboard, you might want to consider a different data model. Having multiple clients modifying the exact same state is going to lead to this type of problem, no matter how fast the connection is. If you look at the drawing whiteboard that Firebase has as an example, you'll see that every user is drawing his own lines; it is just the combined image that everyone sees. Can you do something similar for your use-case? So still sharing the board, but giving every user his/her own "editing" area.

Comment: Alternatively you could use a `transaction` to add the new characters to the data. In a `transaction` you get passed in the existing value of the node and return the new value, so you're in full control at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the transaction hint, that could be a way to work around this.  But how do I prevent step 5 to begin with?  It seems like an AngularFire bug to me.  Browser B which is just sitting there (no cursor in this field) should be able to receive and display an updated value without echoing it back to firebase as if "oh look, I have a new value for you"

Comment: Yeah, that sounds unexpected (even though the problem could/would still occur even if step 5 didn't happen). Does the AngularFire code contain an explicit `set` call for the newly received value?

Comment: Instead of using $bindTo, try using $save and deciding manually when to apply the updates, preferably with a debounce as explained in [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions). You will not get 3-way data bindings to work with this many updates (i.e. one per character) streaming back and forth between multiple clients.

Comment: What's the use of bindTo() if I have to completely work around it for a simple edit field?  I've updated my sample to be even simpler, there is no looping and only one field at the firebase root.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had good success by adding a debounce onto the input.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.field" 
    ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': 500, 'blur': 0} }" />
```

Also, $bindTo isn't strictly necessary here. It's not particularly hard to manually save the data and skip the $bindTo.

```
$scope.data = $firebase(new Firebase(...)).$asObject();

<input type="text" ng-model="data.field" ng-blur="data.$save()" />
```

Comment: I like how clean the manual method is with a simple data.save()

Comment: I tried this with ng-keyup instead of ng-blur and the problem behavior still exists (until debounce is added) so that narrows it down, it's not an issue with bindTo.

Still not ideal for a whiteboard situation because it should stay in sync, but someone can leave the cursor in the field all day thinking others see what they've typed and they don't. See http://jsbin.com/wabafu/4

Debounce is almost the answer except it behaves differently than knockout's throttle feature after I stop typing.  I'll have to open a separate question for that sometime.

Comment: GOT IT!!  I did the same as your second sample except instead of ng-blur, I used ng-change="data.$save()"  That's it, and don't even need the ng-model-options attribute, it now syncs live typing without error.  The problem happens when using the ng-keyup event when ng-change is what I want.

Comment: Awesome. We'll also have some optimizations for this in 0.8.1. I've successfully run using $bindTo with the defaults and haven't had any jumping or oddness.